# Event Handler issue

Tags: c#, vb.net

I found some code online that was C#. I used telerik code converter to convert to VB.net. I am getting an error for the below code

> Closed is already declared as 'public Even Closed(Sender as object, e as System.EventArgs)' in this class.

Same error happens for Shown as well. Anyone have some ideas to fix?

```
 #Region "Events"
    Public Event Closed As EventHandler
    Public Event Shown As EventHandler

    Protected Overridable Sub closed(e As EventArgs)
        Dim handler As EventHandler = Closed

        RaiseEvent handler(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub shown(e As EventArgs)
        Dim handler As EventHandler = Shown

        RaiseEvent handler(Me, e)
    End Sub
#End Region
```

Here is C# code i converted to VB.

```
#region Events
    public event EventHandler Closed;
    public event EventHandler Shown;

    protected virtual void closed(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Closed;

        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void shown(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Shown;

        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Post the original C# code.

Comment: As well as the (compiler?) error you get or a stacktrace... Currently it's guesswork what the problem is...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain He already did "I am getting an error for the below code, Closed is already declared as 'public Even Closed(Sender as object, e as System.EventArgs)' in this class."

Comment: @Marshal I did not realize that was a error message, I thought he was making a statement that he already implemented the Close method but it still was not working.

Comment: `Even`?? Shouldn't this be `Event`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems here.

First, if you are using WinForms, `System.Windows.Forms` already has `Closed` event which conflicts with the event you are creating. So if shadowing is intended you must shadow the event by declaring `Shadows`. But if you are declaring this in a normal class (which doesn't derive from `Form`) you need not worry about it.

```
Public Shadows Event Closed As EventHandler
Public Shadows Event Shown As EventHandler
```

Second, the property name and the event name cannot be same. Vb.Net is case-insensitive in this matter. So you should refactor the names as follows.

```
Public Event Closed As EventHandler
Public Event Shown As EventHandler

Protected Overridable Sub whenClosed(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Closed(Me, e)
End Sub

Protected Overridable Sub whenShown(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent Shown(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: No, in that case C#/VB.NET will ask to create a `new Event ...`, you can (I know this is a terrible design decision) have multiple items in the inheritance path sharing the same name.

Comment: Yes but if the shadowing is intented, it should be shadowed. [Here is what MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya2h8das.aspx). And if shadowing is not intended he should change the event names like `WhenClosed` or `WhenShown`

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me this is a consequence of the fact that [VB.NET is case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300983/is-vb-really-case-insensitive) meaning that an item `shown` is equivalent to an item `Shown`.

You can resolve the problem by renaming (better using some refactoring tool) one of the events, such that the name clash does not appear. You **better do this at the C# project level**, and then run your transcompiler tool again to produce the equivalent VB.NET code.

Comment: @Steve: what do you mean with *tried*, did your code become case-sensitive? Please update your question with new details...