# Setting Multipage Value Attribute Crashes Excel

Tags: excel, vba, crash, multipage

I have a multipage userform control with two pages and button controls for cancel, back, next and finish.

When I set the `multipage.value` attribute in the "back" button sub by subtracting 1, Excel freezes/hangs.

```
Private Sub btn_Back_Click()
        ' Set the buttons
        Me.btn_Next.Enabled = True
        Me.btn_Finish.Enabled = False
        Me.btn_Back.Enabled = False
        Me.multipage_add_xfr.value = Me.multipage_add_xfr.value - 1
End Sub
```

The code to "advance" to the second page by adding 1 works fine in the `btn_Next_Click()` sub:

```
 Me.multipage_add_xfr.value = Me.multipage_add_xfr.value + 1
```

Lastly, on `UserForm_Initialize()`, setting the multipage control to the first page (e.g. value = 0) also crashes Excel.

```
Me.multipage_add_xfr.value = 0
```

**UPADTE** 
The following code works in a new userform that was created within the current project, but the old userform does not.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = False
      Me.CommandButton2.Enabled = True
      Me.MultiPage1.value = Me.MultiPage1.value + 1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
      Me.CommandButton2.Enabled = False
      Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = True
      Me.MultiPage1.value = Me.MultiPage1.value - 1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
      Me.CommandButton2.Enabled = False
      Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = True
      Me.MultiPage1.value = 0
End Sub
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Are there any multipage handlers in your project? Like multipage_add_xfr_Change().

Comment: No, not for the multipage control.

Comment: So, try to experiment: make another project, insert multipage, 2 buttons and make event handlers, no other code.

Comment: May be the problem is internal. I had similar crashes when did batch renames in my project.

Comment: I ran the experiment and noticed that the `.value` attribute was automatically changed to an uppercase "V" in the test project but not in my main project. Is there a broken reference somewhere to the correct libraries?

Comment: VBA is case insensitive. Automatically changing is due to IDE editor that unifies the code. Excel should show an error in case broken references, I suppose.

Comment: P.S. To be correct about case insensitive: at typing stage. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301980/7727881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Private Sub btn_Back_Click()
    If multipage_add_xfr.Value < 1 Then Exit Sub '<~~ Add this one line

    Me.btn_Next.Enabled = True
    Me.btn_Finish.Enabled = False
    Me.btn_Back.Enabled = False
    Me.multipage_add_xfr.Value = Me.multipage_add_xfr.Value - 1
End Sub
```

> Lastly, on UserForm_Initialize(), setting the multipage control to the first page (e.g. value = 0) also crashes Excel.

In this case, delete the control and recreate it. If that still doesn't help then you might have to recreate the form...

You may also want to check if setting it to `0` in `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()` solves the problem?

> Note the change to lower case that vba forces on my code - is that indicative of a problem? – Zephyr Mays 54 mins ago

This usually happens when you declare a variable with the same name

**From Chat**: File Post Mortem confirmed my suspicion. There was a variable declared with the same name.

```
Public Sub update(ByVal value As Long, _
                  Optional ByVal MaxValue As Long = 0, _
                  Optional ByVal Status As String = "", _
                  Optional ByVal DisplayPercent As Boolean = True)
```

Also Multipage was corrupt. Replacing the control solved the problem.

Comment: Setting `value' to 0 on `init()` crashes excel.

Comment: Also, adding the test for page 0 did not fix the issue. However, I noticed that the .value attribute was automatically changed to an uppercase "V" in a test project but not in my main project. Is there a broken reference somewhere to the correct libraries?

Comment: Did you try to put it in `UserForm_Activate()` as i suggested above?

Comment: Yes. Excel still crashes when setting `Me.multipage_add_xfr.value` to 0 in the `UserForm_Activate()` sub, same as the `init()` sub. Note the change to lower case that vba forces on my code - is that indicative of a problem?

Comment: Possibly. have you declared a variable called `value` in your module anywhere? or named a worksheet,module etc with that name?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: I can export the user form, but not the underlying spreadsheets. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Sure. I wanted to see the code in other modules as well. Also a screenshot of your VBA Editor as well if possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195705/discussion-between-zephyr-mays-and-siddharth-rout).